# Año Nuevo algorítmico 2019

Tags: soporte, concursos

A lot of thanks to [@lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855) for the translation!

---

Año Nuevo y [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos), siempre van juntos: ¡Os invitamos a que forméis parte en el concurso de Año Nuevo a las mejores preguntas y respuestas con la etiqueta [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos)!

Las reglas son sencillas: Sólo necesitas publicar preguntas con la etiqueta [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos) y/o contestarlas.

#### Más detalles

El concurso abarca todas las preguntas formuladas a partir del 1 de enero hasta el 31 del mismo mes, con el tag [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos), y también a las respuestas dadas en ese mismo periodo de tiempo a las preguntas con el tag [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos)<sup>*</sup>.

*<sub>Se mirará la fecha de creación de las respuestas, lo que significa que si una respuesta es publicada en una pregunta que fue formulada en el periodo anteriormente descrito, la respuesta también se tendrá en cuenta para calcular el resultado.</sub>

#### Ganadores

Los ganadores serán:

1. La persona que publique una pregunta con la mayor puntuación.
2. La persona que publique una respuesta con la mayor puntuación.
3. La persona que publique una respuesta a su propia pregunta, si la respuesta consigue una mayor puntuación que el resto de respuestas a esa pregunta.
4. La persona que publique una respuesta aceptada con la mayor puntuación.
5. La persona que publique una pregunta con mayor número de respuestas.
6. La persona que publique una pregunta con el mayor número de visitas.
7. La persona que publique más preguntas.
8. La persona que publique más respuestas.

Entre todas las publicaciones que cumplan cada condición, seleccionaremos sólo una, la que tenga la mayor puntuación o la publicada con anterioridad. El concurso estará dividido en dos partes.

- *Primera parte*: Desde el 1 de enero hasta el 10 de enero.
- *Segunda parte*: Desde el 11 de enero hasta el 31 de enero.

Cada parte tendrá sus ganadores, pero solo un premio por persona. Eso quiere decir que si ganas en una categoría en ambas partes del concurso, solo recibirás un premio.

#### El premio

El mayor premio, por supuesto, es el conocimiento y, ¡Sólo por eso merece la pena participar! Además del conocimiento, ¡Los ganadores recibirán *swag*! (merchandising).

#### ¡Empecemos el 1 de enero!

¿Conoces a alguien que pueda formular una gran pregunta con la etiqueta [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos)?  Por favor, ¡invítalo a participar! ¿Conoces a alguien que pueda responderlas? Por favor, ¡invítalos también!

Estamos deseando recibir vuestras preguntas y respuestas de la etiqueta [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos). ¡Recordad suscribiros a la etiqueta para no perderos ninguna publicación! ¡Buena suerte!

**Importante**: Los resultados serán contados 10 días después del final de cada parte del concurso para así dar las mismas oportunidades a todos de recibir votos.

---

#### ¿Cómo vamos a identificar a los ganadores?

Usaremos las siguientes consultas SQL en [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

1. La persona que publique una pregunta con la mayor puntuación:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
2. La persona que publique una respuesta con la mayor puntuación:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
3. La persona que publique una respuesta a su propia pregunta, si la respuesta consigue una mayor puntuación que el resto de respuestas a esa pregunta (esta consulta busca auto-respuestas):

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.OwnerUserId = parent.OwnerUserId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
4. La persona que publique una respuesta aceptada con la mayor puntuación:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.Id = parent.AcceptedAnswerId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
5. La persona que publique una pregunta con mayor número de respuestas:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.AnswerCount, p.Score  
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.AnswerCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
6. La persona que publique una pregunta con el mayor número de visitas:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, m.ViewCount, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
     Join PostMetadata m on m.PostId = p.Id
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY m.ViewCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
7. La persona que publique más preguntas:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```
8. La persona que publique más respuestas:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 175 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```

Comment: Hi Nicholas! Would the swag be from SE, or SOes specifically ?

Comment: @lois6b Thank you for the translation and ... the price is a top secret which even I do not know.

Comment: I love secrets... but I hate the waiting for their reveal hehehe

Comment: Why was this tag chosen ?

Comment: @lois6b I think most of us like time when we were studying at university. I would say that that time at least for me is associated with algorithms and new technologies. The contest is an attempt to turn the time back and experience that feeling again :)

Comment: ¿Por qué hay comentarios en inglés en SOes, de qué me he perdido? Además, ¿las preguntas con la etiqueta `algoritmo` deben estar relacionadas con ciencias de la computación o (xor más bien) ingeniería de software?

Comment: @dwarandae Nicholas es el nuevo Community manager de SOes y no sabe español, es ruso.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky I think there might be something funky with the queries or the data (although I don't see anything wrong). I asked an [tag:algoritmos] question that got several answers within the allotted time period, but they don't show up in the results.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hi! It might happen if I get it right. SEDE is a dump which gets updated weekly. That means if you ask a question but a new dump has not been deployed yet, you will not see the question in the results.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of thanks for the translation to [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh).

---

### Año Nuevo algorítmico 2019, resultados de la segunda sesión

Por favor, ¡únanse a las felicitaciones de los ganadores de la segunda sesión!

#### Autor de la pregunta con la puntuación más alta, la pregunta que obtiene la mayor cantidad de respuestas y la que tiene más vistas.

[@enxaneta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/98629/enxaneta) con una pregunta "[Cómo dibujar un corazón: (el algoritmo del corazón)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/230120/10)" que obtuvo 24 votos positivos, 11 respuestas y 374 visitas!

#### Autor de una respuesta con la puntuación más alta.

[@devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept) con [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/229007/10) a una pregunta "[¿Cómo organizar una lista de colores de forma eficiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/228408/10)". La respuesta tiene 21 votos a favor.

#### Autor de una respuesta a su propia pregunta, si la respuesta obtiene una puntuación más alta que cualquier otra respuesta a la pregunta

[@Urres.Alejandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/30418/urres-alejandro) con una pregunta auto respondida “[¿Cómo se puede aplicar el acertijo del lobo, la cabra y la col?](Https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233331/10)”.

#### Autor de una respuesta aceptada la puntuación más alta.

[@Mauricio Contreras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112837/mauricio-contreras) con [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/229319/10) a una pregunta "[Calcular el área de un triángulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/229310/10)". La respuesta tiene 11 votos a favor.

#### Autor de la mayoría de las preguntas

[@enxaneta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/98629/enxaneta) ha hecho 2 preguntas con 25 votos positivos y 10 respuestas en total.

#### Autor de la mayoría de las respuestas

[@Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31764/patricio-moracho) ha respondido 3 preguntas con 16 votos positivos para las respuestas en total.

¡Muchas gracias a todos los que participaron! El Año Nuevo algorítmico 2019 ha terminado, pero por favor, seguid haciendo y respondiendo preguntas con [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos). Estoy seguro de que estas preguntas son una hermosa decoración de la base de conocimientos que causa muchas emociones positivas en la comunidad.

Comment: La respuesta de @abulafia en [¿Cómo organizar una lista de colores de forma eficiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/228408/7176) tiene más votos que la de devconcept. Quizá no era así en el momento de cerrarse el concurso pero me suena que esa respuesta iba por delante

Answer (score 2):

A lot of thanks to [@KacosPro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22721/kacospro) for the translation!

---

## Año Nuevo algorítmico 2019, resultados de la primera sesión

Por favor, ¡únase a las felicitaciones de los ganadores de la primera sesión!

#### Autor de la pregunta con la puntuación más alta, la pregunta que obtiene la mayor cantidad de respuestas y la que tiene más vistas.

[@Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) con la pregunta "[¿Cómo organizar una lista de colores de forma eficiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/228408/10)" que obtuvo 22 votos, 4 respuestas y 243 visitas. ¡Es un resultado realmente increíble!

Autor de una respuesta con la puntuación más alta

[@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) con la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/228430/10) a la pregunta "[¿Cómo organizar una lista de colores de forma eficiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/228408/10)". ¡La respuesta obtuvo 19 votos positivos!

Autor de una respuesta aceptada con la puntuación más alta

[@Dєηyη Crawford](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/44653/) con la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226589/10) a la pregunta "[Algoritmo para convertir un número binario a un número entero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226586/10)". ¡5 votos positivos y aceptada!

#### Autor de la mayoría de las preguntas

Todos los que han hecho preguntas con la etiqueta [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos) durante la primera sesión, sólo han hecho una pregunta. La primera pregunta "[Algoritmo para convertir un número binario a un número entero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226586/10)" fue formulada por [@Alan BM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/96571/alan-bm). Obtuvo 5 votos y dos respuestas.

#### Autor de la mayoría de las respuestas

La situación con las respuestas es la misma que con las preguntas: todos respondieron una sola pregunta durante la primera sesión. La primera [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226588/10) fue publicada por [@Juan Pinzón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2429/juan-pinz%C3%B3n) a la pregunta "[Algoritmo para convertir un número binario a un número entero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226586/10)".

---

¡Muchas gracias a todos los que participaron, la segunda sesión del Algoritmo de Año Nuevo 2019 está en pleno apogeo! Todavía tienes la oportunidad de convertirte en uno de los ganadores. ¡Por favor, hagan y respondan a las preguntas con la etiqueta [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos)!

---

Comment: Genial!, Muchas Gracias!