# ¡Feliz Año Nuevo 7E3!

Tags: soporte

A lot of thanks to [@lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) for the translation.

---

En la víspera de Año Nuevo, permitidnos recapitular los momentos del año 2018 que mejor recordamos y también pensar en los planes para el año que viene.

#### ¿Qué recuerdas del año 2018?

Cada uno de nosotros puede destacar el que para ellos fue el momento más importante relacionado con esta comunidad. Para mi, fue la oportunidad de trabajar con todos los sitios internacionales, en particular con el vuestro ( muchas gracias a todos vosotros por vuestro apoyo y ayuda). Empezamos trabajando juntos en [nuestra etiqueta en MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/international-sites), [escribimos un manifiesto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/274323), y empezamos a compartir [problemas, descubrimientos e iniciativas entre las comunidades internacionales](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323).

¡Estoy seguro que tenéis momentos que compartir con la comunidad también!
*Por favor contadnos, en la sección de respuestas, qué recordáis cada uno sobre 2018*

#### El año en números

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | en español         |  en español       |
|                    | 2017               |  2018             |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Preguntas         |     41 503         |    50 176         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Respuestas        |     42 268         |    44 573         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Nuevos usuarios   |     41 823         |    39 181         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

La comunidad crece día a día, como también el conocimiento que creamos. En este año todos hicimos un trabajo fenomenal juntos, como la tabla de arriba refleja. Muchas gracias a todos los que formasteis parte.

#### ¡El año que viene tenemos que hacer muchas cosas!

Me gustaría destacar algunas cosas en las que podemos ser pieza fundamental en el futuro.

- *¡Más personas significa más ideas!* Sería genial ver a todos los que han formado parte en Stack Overflow en español de los últimos años, y las nuevas personas que seguro traerán algo de sí mismas: Algunos compartirán conocimiento sobre interfaces de aplicaciones, otros escribirán con entusiasmo sobre controladores y otros añadirán nuevos procesos a la comunidad. Las personas son lo más importante en Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, invitad a vuestros amigos a compartir conocimiento en el sitio y contadles nuestra [misión](/help/manifesto). Ellos harán de SOes, con su participación, un sitio más interesante.
- *Los problemas actuales con las comunidades internacionales, descubrimientos, e iniciativas en MSE*. Podemos incrementar nuestra eficiencia [intercambiando ideas unos con otros en MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323). Además, nuestros problemas comunes recibirán atención extra y nuevas e interesantes soluciones. Es muy posible que colaborando se acelere el ritmo en el que cada comunidad internacional crece. Como se dice, *"dos cabezas piensan mejor que una, y más si son de culturas distintas"*.
- *Crear nuestro propio conocimiento*. Si ordenamos todas las preguntas por el número de veces que han sido vistas, se puede ver que en el *top 3* de cada sitio internacional hay al menos una pregunta que ha sido auto-respondida (y esto también es cierto para SO en inglés). A menudo, las propias respuestas recogen la información más importante sobre un problema técnico específico de una manera canónica. Estas preguntas y respuestas son de gran interés por nuestra parte. Sería genial ver más preguntas y respuestas de este tipo el próximo año. Estoy seguro que recibirán mucha atención y recibimiento positivo.

Creo que la oportunidad de influenciar la vida de miles de personas con sólo una respuesta fue, es y será la principal motivación y recompensa para participar en este sitio. Sería genial si el próximo año, nos centramos en nuestra colección de respuestas detalladas a cada pregunta sobre programación de nuestra comunidad. Estoy seguro que colaborando nos traerá muy buenos pensamientos positivos.

**¡Feliz Año Nuevo 7E3!**

[image]

¡Casi me olvido! [Año Nuevo nunca viene solo...](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3842/10)

Comment: Feliz año nuevo 2019 para los miembros de la comunidad y sus familias, 2019 será aún mejor para es.stackoverflow.com