# ¿Preguntas basadas en opiniones en retos?

Tags: discusión, temática

A raíz del reto [Año Nuevo algorítmico 2019](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3842/a%C3%B1o-nuevo-algor%C3%ADtmico-2019?cb=1) reto y de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231595/cu%C3%A1l-es-tu-implementaci%C3%B3n-de-fractal-favorita-en-javascript-o-css) pregunta que hice me ha surgido la duda. ¿Son válidas las preguntas basadas en opiniones en los retos?

No sé si esto rompería la filosofía del sitio. Al menos personalmente los retos como este los concibo como una oportunidad de aprender sobre un tema en concreto más que como la búsqueda de una solución concreta.

En dicho reto hay ahora mismo varias preguntas abiertas y, hasta donde yo veo, todas están basadas en opiniones:

[¿Cómo organizar una lista de colores de forma eficiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228408/c%C3%B3mo-organizar-una-lista-de-colores-de-forma-eficiente)

[Cómo dibujar un corazón: (el algoritmo del corazón)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230120/c%C3%B3mo-dibujar-un-coraz%C3%B3n-el-algoritmo-del-coraz%C3%B3n)

[Algoritmo para crear polígonos regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230444/algoritmo-para-crear-pol%C3%ADgonos-regulares)

He buscado en el meta de SO pero no he encontrado nada.

¿Qué opináis vosotros (valga la redundancia)?

Comment: Por una parte, yo seria estricto. Por otra, los retos atraen participación. Limitando las publicaciones (y depende de la etiqueta del reto) podría perderse esa participación de usuarios. He de seguir pensandolo. Un saludo

Comment: Tal y como está planteado el reto ahora mismo no creo que se deban aceptar preguntas basadas en opiniones ya que abre una puerta que tal vez después no seamos capaces de cerrar. No hay manera de diferenciar las preguntas del reto del resto. Como ha comentado [@fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3873/7176) quedan las preguntas y sus respuestas en el sitio igual que las demás, los usuarios pueden pensar que son preguntas válidas y cuando una pregunta suya se cierre por estar basada en opiniones no entenderán que criterio cierra unas preguntas y premia otras.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yo creo que absolutamente NO.

El reto pasará y será algo que únicamente tendrá referencia en Meta (y supongo que en el armario de los ganadores, en forma de alguna prenda), pero en el sitio principal quedarán unas preguntas y respuestas que estarán dando ejemplo de futuro. Y como ya se decidió, y parece seguir habiendo consenso, que las preguntas sobre opiniones no se aceptan, no creo pertinente dejarla abierta.

Mencionas tres preguntas y dices que se basan en opiniones:

- [¿Cómo organizar una lista de colores de forma eficiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228408/c%C3%B3mo-organizar-una-lista-de-colores-de-forma-eficiente)
- [Cómo dibujar un corazón: (el algoritmo del corazón)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230120/c%C3%B3mo-dibujar-un-coraz%C3%B3n-el-algoritmo-del-coraz%C3%B3n)
- [Algoritmo para crear polígonos regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230444/algoritmo-para-crear-pol%C3%ADgonos-regulares)

No creo que sea el caso. Las preguntas sobre opiniones que no se aceptan son aquellas que, como dice la descripción de este motivo de cierre:

> Muchas buenas preguntas generan cierto grado de opinión según la experiencia de los expertos, pero casi todas las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica.

Estas tres preguntas pueden generar controversia, pero la validez de las respuestas es resoluble con argumentos técnicos.

En [la pregunta que mencionas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231595/83), por contra, se leen cosas como:

> Me gustaría recopilar algoritmos que representen fractales.

O incluso previamente había la frase:

> ***¿Cuál es vuestro fractal favorito?***

Esto es algo no objetivable ni existe criterio alguno que pueda determinar cuál es la "buena" respuesta o cuál es mejor que otra. Por tanto, está a caballo entre preguntas de opiniones y preguntas de listas, ambas no aceptadas.

Por todo ello, creo que esta pregunta en particular debería cerrarse si mantiene su formato actual. Y, en general, las preguntas fuera de ámbito no deberían computar para los retos.

---

Lo que me resulta entre curioso y preocupante es que a día de hoy tenga apenas dos votos de cierre pese a que [el comentario de blonfu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231595/c%C3%B3mo-dibujar-un-fractal#comment430058_231595) tenga 6 votos positivos:

> ¿Se puede hacer una pregunta basada en opiniones aunque sea para un reto? No lo tengo claro.

La salud del sitio es cosa de todos y si no votamos para cerrar lo que no es pertinente, difícilmente lo mejoraremos.

Comment: Coincido en varios puntos pero sigo viendo las otras como basadas en opiniones. La única diferencia es la redacción de la misma. La mía seguramente sea más directa pero, por poner un ejemplo, en la que se pregunta sobre algoritmos para dibujar corazones pone esta frase:  "Y como que se acerca San Valentin me gustaría recoger algoritmos para dibujar corazones en CSS, en canvas, en SVG o en lo que os parezca.". No veo la diferencia entre eso y: "La idea del reto es que pongáis vuestro algoritmo favorito con una implementación en javascript (SVG, Canvas,...), CSS o lo que os parezca."

Comment: Respecto a que te parezca preocupante que la pregunta siga abierta supongo que sigue abierta a raíz de los comentarios que hemos ido poniendo (primero en el que me sugerías cambiar la pregunta y luego en el que comentaba que quería debatirlo en meta)

Comment: @Kiko_L no he mirado las otras preguntas con detenimiento, hice leídas diagonales. Lo que comentas tiene lógica y si la esencia de la pregunta del corazón es "ver cómo se haría" sin definir criterio de cuál es el "mejor" algoritmo, entonces entiendo que también se basaría en opiniones.

Comment: No he leído todas las preguntas con la etiqueta [tag:algoritmos] pero pero las tres que se ponen de ejemplo aunque quizás están rozando el límite no se basan tan claramente en opiniones ya que preguntan por algoritmos para hacer algo concreto y no por un algoritmo cualquiera.

Comment: @Kiko_L entiendo, si bien llevaba un día entero en la cola de revisión ([salió al eliminarla[(https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/231595/timeline)) y es algo que a un usuario nuevo difícilmente dejaríamos pasar. Entiéndeme, ya dije en los comentarios que lo que planteas es bonito y la pregunta en sí está muy currada, con las definiciones y creaciones y demás, de allí que sugiriera "salvarla" convirtiéndola en una pregunta que permitiera evaluar las respuestas de una forma más objetiva.

Comment: Tranqui, no tengo problema en eliminarla. Es sólo que me había surgido esa duda, sobre todo viendo el resto de preguntas del reto. Si os parece la dejo esta tarde por si alguien más quiere opinar del tema y la borro después.